# Visual Studio Is not displaying all Installed APIs

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Goodday, I have had Visual Studio and Xamarin for a while and recently i have started to learn android development. I have made a pretty cool android app now, my problem is that i had APIs 23, 19 and 18 installed before. Now i want my app to support android 2.2 (API 8) i have installed the SDK Platform and Google APis for API 8 but it doesnt show up in the APP manifest for minimum api to support in Visual Studio, i have tried restarting VS and even the system but it only displays APIs 23, 18 and 19.

Am i missing something please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is a bug. But if you want to change your minimum API level just collapse Properties, open AndroidManifest.xml and change `android:minSdkVersion` attribute in `uses-sdk` tag to 8.